# Facebook App Login: How to control expiration date of an image URL I got?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an app, which uses the facebook login. After login the user must set additional informations and a profile picture, with the picture being provided from that logged in facebook account as well. Now the whole account details, including the URL to that profile picture, are saved in my database.

To my surprise the profile picture has suddenly stopped working. Opening it's URL in a browser gives me this message "URL signature expired"

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p720x720/10846350_10204966809307370_2779189783437306470_n.jpg?oh=245bbada6c23f280a1e531e724be85ed&oe=56894D69

Downloading those photos and save them to my own server is not really an option for me. Is there anything I can do to make that URL durable?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, Facebook’s CDN URLs may expire - you are not supposed to store them for long-term use.

But you can request any user’s profile picture (as long as you have their global/app-scoped user id), by simply referring to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture // Mark Zuckerberg’s profile pic
```

– that URL issues a redirect to the current CDN URL for the image.

That image is rather small though, 50px x 50px – you can use `https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture?type=large` to request a larger version. That will give you the profile image in 200px x 200px (or close to that, if the user did not upload a square image.)

Note that some pictures require an access token to be retrieved. For example `https://graph.facebook.com/72256131540/picture`
returns a generic image of a questionmark unless you add an access token like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/72256131540/picture?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

**UPDATE:**

This should still work the same without problems, if you are requesting the profile picture via an app-scoped user ID. If you are requesting it via an old, global user ID or a page-scoped user id, then you will have to include an access token now - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture#requirements has the details.

(App or page access tokens should not be exposed in public client-side code, so when using those, the request should be made only server-side.)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't necessarily want to get the user's current profile picture, but it can also be any other one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then either download and store them on your own server, or fetch a fresh CDN URL by going through the user’s profile pictures album (requires permission, of course.)

Comment: CBroe, Do you have idea is there anything similar for other providers. I asked primary for Google, Instagram and VKontakte

Comment: As pointed out in the response, refetching the image is quite simple (it could even be automated). There does not seem to be any need for the token being present (just the user identifier). This API should also give the JSON response with new CDN URL in case redirect is disabled: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: could you please specify why would some pictures require an access token? and how will I be able to still access the picture when the token expires?

Comment: this method is expired now. any other solution you can suggest?

Comment: @MubeenMubarik I added an update to the answer; with certain types of user IDs, this requires an access token now.

Comment: @CBroe any chance to get access token dynamically here ?

Comment: @MubeenMubarik not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: is there any solution to get access token directly regardless of performing the series of steps like app creation and then get the token as mentioned in facebook graph api developer platform

Comment: @MubeenMubarik no, there is not. Having an app id is the basis for doing pretty much anything with the Facebook API. (The token generation itself does not have to happen in Graph API Explorer of course, that is mainly a test tool for developers - usually, you would get a user access token, by having the user login to your app.)

Comment: @CBroe yes but the access tokens also get expiry after some time, i want to automate the process so I get the updated token every time i need

Comment: You can not “automate” the process of getting a user access token (if that is what you are talking about), this always needs user interaction.