# Firebase : User's facebook avatar photo returning "URL signature expired" after recent update

Tags: facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

After updating to the latest release of Firebase and FB login package, all FB user profile avatar photos are returning "URL signature expired".

this is the version of the packages I am using

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.33.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-web/issues/21). After a while, [Facebook photoURLs expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580136/facebook-app-login-how-to-control-expiration-date-of-an-image-url-i-got). You will need to get a new Facebook access tokens and re-authenticate with it to update the photoURLs.

Comment: the URL is not available even for one second it s returning null.